# The connector is displaying an empty field during drop down in mule3 custom connector for enum

Tags: mule, mule-component

On developing a custom connector in mule3, I have categories as an enum, which has functional, technical, performance drop down fields. But i am not sure why i am getting empty row in the drop down and this should not occur.

```
package org.mule.modules.apipflogger;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.mule.api.annotations.Connector;
import org.mule.api.annotations.Processor;
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Default;
import org.mule.api.annotations.param.Optional;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionManager;
import corp.api.Categories;
import org.mule.api.MuleContext;
import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
import org.mule.api.MuleException;

@Connector(name = "apipflogger", friendlyName = "Apipflogger")
public class ApipfloggerConnector {

protected Log logger;

protected String message;

protected String level = "DEBUG";

protected MuleContext muleContext;

protected ExpressionManager expressionManager;

protected void initLogger(Categories category) {
    if (category != null) {
        logger = LogFactory.getLog(category.name());
    } else {
        logger = LogFactory.getLog(ApipfloggerConnector.class);
    }
    expressionManager = muleContext.getExpressionManager();
}

@Processor(friendlyName = "Custom Logger")
public MuleEvent customLogger(MuleEvent muleEvent, @Optional String message, @Default("INFO") LogLevel level,
        @Default("Technical") Categories category) throws MuleException {
    muleContext = muleEvent.getMuleContext();
    setLevel(level.name());
    initLogger(category);
    log(muleEvent, message, level);
    return muleEvent;
}

protected void log(MuleEvent event, String message, LogLevel level) {
    if (event == null) {
        logWithLevel(null, level);
    } else {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
            logWithLevel(event.getMessage(), level);
        } else {
            LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.valueOf(level.name());
            if (LogLevel.valueOf(level.name()).isEnabled(logger))
                logLevel.log(logger, expressionManager.parse(message, event));

        }
    }
}

protected void logWithLevel(Object object, LogLevel level) {
    LogLevel logLevel = LogLevel.valueOf(level.name());
    if (logLevel.isEnabled(logger))
        logLevel.log(logger, object);
}

public void setLevel(String level) {
    this.level = level.toUpperCase();
}

public MuleContext getMuleContext() {
    return muleContext;
}

public void setMuleContext(MuleContext muleContext) {
    this.muleContext = muleContext;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public enum LogLevel {
    ERROR {
        public void log(Log logger, Object object) {
            logger.error(object);
        }

        public boolean isEnabled(Log logger) {
            return logger.isErrorEnabled();
        }
    },
    WARN {
        public void log(Log logger, Object object) {
            logger.warn(object);
        }

        public boolean isEnabled(Log logger) {
            return logger.isWarnEnabled();
        }
    },
    INFO {
        public void log(Log logger, Object object) {
            logger.info(object);
        }

        public boolean isEnabled(Log logger) {
            return logger.isInfoEnabled();
        }
    },
    DEBUG {
        public void log(Log logger, Object object) {
            logger.debug(object);
        }

        public boolean isEnabled(Log logger) {
            return logger.isDebugEnabled();
        }
    },
    TRACE {
        public void log(Log logger, Object object) {
            logger.trace(object);
        }

        public boolean isEnabled(Log logger) {
            return logger.isTraceEnabled();
        }
    };

    public abstract void log(Log param1Log, Object param1Object);

    public abstract boolean isEnabled(Log param1Log);
}
}
public enum Categories {
   Performance,Technical,Functional
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not displaying because it is giving precedence to import with Categories  - `import corp.api.Categories;`

I think there are two Categories available one in import and other as defined enum.

If you remove `import corp.api.Categories;` then it should work fine.

Comment: import corp.api.Categories is the custom one, if i remove this, whereever it is being used, compiler throws an error Categoreis cannot be resolved to type. This is custom enum according to our requirement. Can you let me know anything to be done ??

Comment: You can test with two approach - 1. Rename Categories enum 2. Give full qualified name in processor like - org.mule.modules.apipflogger.Categories ... please do the testing and let us know your feedback..

Comment: Yes tried both the approaches, the result is same. I mean the empty row is occuring in configuration.

Comment: Can you share code and ui screenshot for first approach?

Comment: @Processor(friendlyName ="Custom Logger")
 public MuleEvent apipfLogger(MuleEvent muleEvent, @Placement(order=1, group="General")@Optional String message, 
   @Default(value="Technical") CustomCategory category, 
   @Default(value="INFO") CustomLogger customLogger 
   ) throws MuleException { 

Screenshot is same. Just renamed the category to customCategory.

Comment: It is the same abhishkek. i mean the screenshot which is posted in the qn. Same UI.

Comment: If it is same then your latest changes is not coming on UI.As you have changed to CustomCategory then you should see custom category on UI. Try to uninstall and install again.

Comment: Sorry i reread on your question. You are worried about empty row.. i think this is by default from Mulesoft. So you can ignore this part or you can raise with MuleSoft.  Apologies for clue on other directions.

Comment: okay. I have raised in help.mulesoft/s/forum. https://help.mulesoft.com/s/question/0D52T00005CRexNSAT/mule3-custom-connector-is-displaying-empty-field-during-drop-down-in-mule3-custom-connector-for-enumi-have-categories-as-an-enumwhich-has-functional-technical-performance-drop-down-fieldsbut-i-am-not-sure-why-i-am-getting-empty-row-in-the-drop-down

But if some user clicks on the empty row, it should not allow to click or have some constraint. cant we do something like that and any proof that this is being given by mulesoft by default. ?? please let me know.

Comment: If they select on empty row then default value will be provided to Processor. It shouldn’t by any issue..

Comment: Yes it will take the default which we have given. But cant i override this behaviour, because in the logger component, we see empty as one of the drop down option. Can we do like this. ?? One more any proof or docs telling this is by mulesoft given.

Comment: i think NO, unless MuleSoft provide fix in Devkit :)

Comment: Are u 100% sure , that this empty row is being appended by mulesoft side ??

Comment: Yes.. because i also developed multiple connectors and i can see same behaviour in all connectors..

Comment: okay cool. One more can u do code review of my code, any optimisation required ? or any modifications ??

Comment: @the_code Have a look at [https://codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: what to look at here ? I couldnt get it.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKumar , in this code , when i am trying to print #[payload], entire message is getting printed., how do i execute as a normal logger. means just printing the payload ?

Comment: how do we write a test case for custom connector? Any resource u can share with me..

Comment: i want to mock a muleEvent? any tutorial i can follow

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKumar ,  i am developing a mule4 custom connector, i need to use same value(message, category, classification and level) in mule under basic settings as general, how do i do it. i am getting as a seperate configuration window.